# Let $f\in R[-\pi,\pi]$. Show $\exists g\in C[-\pi,\pi]$ satisfying $||f-g||_2<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f\in R[-\pi,\pi]$. Show $\exists g\in C[-\pi,\pi]$ satisfying $||f-g||_2<\epsilon$

(where $\epsilon>0, R[a,b]$ is the space of Riemann Integrable functions on $[a,b]$, $C[a,b]$ is the space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$)

Thoughts/Attempt:

I'm not sure where to start on this one, so I'll just state some ideas that I've tried.

By definition of $||f-g||_2$ in the $L_2$ norm, what we want is to find a $g\in C[-\pi,\pi]$ such that

$$||f-g||_2=\left(\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f(x)-g(x))^2\mathop{dx}\right)^{1/2}<\epsilon$$

Assume $f$ is Riemann Integrable on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and suppose $g$ is a uniformly continuous function since we want to show there exists a continuous function $g$ on the compact interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. By definition of uniform continuity, we have that $\forall\epsilon >0\exists\delta\forall x,y: |x-y|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$

I've also thought that if I can define  a sequence of polygonal functions $g_n$ in such a way where each $g_i$ a polygonal function made by partitioning a function up into numerous subintervals $(x_\delta,x_{\delta +1})$, then the limit of this sequence would make the partitions smaller and smaller  and it would be a continuous linear piecewise function. But I don't know if I can show that this converges to a Riemann Integrable function $f$ under the $L_2$ norm.

But I'm not sure if I can do anything from here, or if any of these are in the right direction.

*A hint would be preferable over a full solution if possible.* Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some steps:

1. You can always find a step function $\phi$ (i.e. piece-wise constant) arbitrarily close to your $f$ (by the construction of Riemann intregral)
2. You can always build a continuous function $g$ which is arbitrarily close to $\phi$ in $L^2$ norm - by defining it piece-wise on each step of $\phi$.

If you need further hints: remember the behaviour of $x^n$ on the interval $[-1,1]$.